# TinyMCE: Backspace Problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, angularjs, django-tinymce

Suppose there is already a text say `Hello World` in the text area of TinyMCE. Now I delete the space between Hello and World and make it `HelloWorld`. Immediately I add a space between Hello and World to get `Hello World`.(Expected Output)

After the above process, I save the text. The text that gets saved is `HelloWorld` (Without Space). What is expected is `Hello World` but what gets saved it `HelloWorld`.

Has anyone encountered this? If so please tell me how to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, i didn't encounter anything like that, can you show use a live example or a tinymce fiddle (fiddle.tinymce.com/) ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We have actually used a AngularJS wrapper for TinyMCE Plugin. I don't think it is actually causing the issue. I'll try to put in a fiddle (If my manager permits).

Comment: I'm really sorry guys... I'm not supposed to post any code :-(

Comment: looks like we can't help you then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's hard to answer without seeing the actual code, and i'm quite new to angular, but since you've noted you are using your own wrapper, i would recommend using a more formal solution, it tends to be less error prone.

check this out:
http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-tinymce

really hope it helps